# FTP reopen the connection

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve FTP re-connectivity in python whenever the connection is lost.
Whenever connectivity is lost, I will call Connect() function as below.
To simulate disconnection I am calling ftp.logout() and then trying to download a file which would throw an exception , in the exception handler I am calling the Connect() function.

```
ftp = FTP("hostname")
def Connect():
    print('Calling Connect')
    ftp.login("user","password")
```

I am running into below exception
 AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'")

Can anybody throw some light on this?

Comment: I think you need to re-open the connection to the host - when you logout, you don't just log out the user, you "lose the host" as well.

Comment: Where does this happen in relation to `sendall`? Post the `try` block please.

Comment: You have not posted the code that's throwing the `AttributeError`. Unless you show *all* the relevant source, and the *full* stacktrace, there's very little we can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can solve the problem by re-initializing the `ftp` variable inside your `connect()` function:

```
def Connect():
  ftp = FTP("hostname")
  print('Calling Connect')
  ftp.login("user","password")
```

Comment: I am using ftp variable in other functions, so I want it to be global.

Comment: It's OK for `ftp` to be global - but you need to re-initialize it inside the `Connect()` function.